# Does a bot get notified when it's uninstalled from a tenant?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm testing out a bot right now via an uploaded custom (sideloaded) app. I can see that when I add the bot to a team or remove it from a team that I get an activity with a type of conversationUpdate with the bot's ID in the members added or members removed element.

Is there a specific activity or other event that the bot gets when it's removed from the tenant entirely? Do I just have to track all teams the bot was added to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teams does not yet have a well-defined concept of being added at the tenant level. We will be adding that in the first half of 2018.

In the meantime, yes, you have to track it on a team-by-team basis I'm afraid.